# Beginner in Ruby, Diagonal Difference stuck

Tags: arrays, ruby, data-structures, iteration

I am doing a HackerRank question of Diagonal Difference.

Here is my code:

```
def diagonalDifference(arr)

  first = 0
  second = 0
  i=0
  puts arr
    while i < arr.length
      first += arr[i][i]
      second += arr[i][(arr.size-1)-i]
      i+=1
    end
    (first + second).abs
end
```

I can't solve it. I am not sure which part went wrong. Please help me with this.

Comment: Hey, without having fully read and understood your code: It always helps if you give details on what went wrong: did your code raise an error, in what cases it didn't satisfy the question?

Comment: The [diagonal difference](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference/problem) question (which I had to google, to understand what it is you're talking about -- you should always include the full context of the question directly in your post!) is based on a **matrix** - which you've presumably implemented as an array of arrays. What is your input? What is the expected output? What result did you actually get?

Comment: Actually wait, I've just spotted the silly mistake you made... Will answer below...

Answer (score 3):

The question is asking for the absolute **difference**.

Your code uses:

```
(first + second).abs
```

Instead of the correct formula:

```
(first - second).abs
```

Comment: I would advise learning the basics of how to debug ruby code -- for example, you could try [using `pry`](https://learn.co/lessons/debugging-with-pry) to step through the code and investigate what values are equal to at any given time. (This is often much more helpful than sticking `puts` statements all over the place!)